# SQL query on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-to-linq-conversion

How do I do this sql query to entity framework?

```
select 
id,
column1,
column2 =  case when (select max(column2) from table1 b where b.id = a.id) = a.column2 
then 'Positive' else 'Negative' end
from table1 a
```

Comment: Do you mean how to write it into Linq To Entities or do you want to execute this sql command though DbContext?

Comment: yes, how to write it on into Linq To Entities

Comment: Sorry, but I just read the sql command and I have some notification. (select max(column2) from table1 b where b.id = a.id). Beacuse of the where caluse it will always have one record in result. So the column2 always 'Positive'. (if id is really primary key as I expected)

Comment: your right, sorry, id is not the primary key,

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from t in context.table1
            let column2_temp = context.table1.Where(p=>p.id==t.id).Max(p=>p.column2)
            let column2 = column2_temp == t.column2? "Positive" : "Negative"
            select new {t.id, column2}
```